# How to programmatically add a FacebookAds adView to the top of the screen in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, ionic-framework, ionic4, facebook-ads-api

I am new to Android development and have created an app in Ionic4. I came across this ionic plugin which lets you integrate Facebook Ads in Ionic Apps and I am able to show a test banner ad at the bottom of the screen using this plugin.

How can I tweak this code to show the banner ad at the top of the screen?

Plugin code link: https://github.com/merbin2012/cordova-plugin-codeplay-facebookads-free/blob/master/src/android/codeplayfacebookads.java

As I am not developing natively, doing this by modifying code in the .xml file is not an option here. I need to purely do it using java. I tried changing a bit of code in facebookBannerAdsShow() (line 310 in the linked file) by using RelativeLayout but to no success.
Can someone help me here?